# bug ScrollTop on Safari ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do a responsive website with bootstrap with anchor html in my navigation. In my nav bar I have a logo , when the user click on it , the site scroll to the top. And everything works in desktop. But in the  ipad with Safari when I click to the logo to scroll to the top , this is working only once. And my nav bar with anchor bug after that.

How fix that?

My code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.brand').bind('click',function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'normal');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Try "on" bind method

As of Jquery 1.7+ the better approach is to use "on" method not bind.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".brand").on("click", function ()
 { 
  $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'normal');
alert('image is clicked')
 });

});
```

Thanks AB

Comment: I have the same problem after changing that:s

Comment: Why is `on` "better"? And where does the `img` selector suddenly come from?

Comment: img selector means ur logo is an image right? give its id der

Comment: the on() method is the new replacement for the bind(), live() and delegate() methods. This method brings a lot of consistency to the API, as it simplifies the jQuery code base.

Comment: I checked it. The function works only once on Safari but it works everytime on chrome etc. It is my problem i want it works everytime :S And apparently Safary doesn't like scrolltop :s

Comment: .scrollTop would work on $("body") but not $("html, body")...This should work in safari

Comment: I checked again i do that ans it works only once :s I don't know why.     $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.brand').on('click',function(){
  $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'normal');
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Read somewhere that mobile Safari doesn't scroll body, it moves the viewport, so you need to scroll div.

If you are using jQuery, you can just use [scrollTo plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) or hardware accelerated [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#scroll) - it worked for me. Note that velocity requires scrolled element to have a non-static position (i.e. relative, absolute, fixed)